# Balancer not working in hdfs HA

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, ambari, bigdata

When I try to run balancer:

`HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs hdfs --config /etc/hadoop/conf.balancer/conf/ balancer -threshold 5`

or

`HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs hdfs balancer -fs hdfs://hdp`

I get the following error:

**java.io.IOException: Another Balancer is running**

Of course I have read about this error, and for the moment I think that I have found the solution:

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/4595/balancer-not-working-in-hdfs-ha.html

but, when I apply this solution.. I get the new error:

**java.io.IOException: Couldn't create proxy provider class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider.**

And every hadoop command gives error exception:

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```

-ls: java.net.UnknownHostException: hdp

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the answer maybe it will be useful for someone.

This solution works: [balancer-not-working-in-hdfs-ha.html](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/4595/balancer-not-working-in-hdfs-ha.html)

Just, please remember to delete rpc for single NN and don't touch HA settings.